# Makefile error in C

Tags: c, makefile

```
CC   = gcc
OPTS = -W -O3

SRCDIR=./src
OBJDIR=./obj
INCDIR=./inc
BINDIR=./bin

SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Functions.c \
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Function1.c \ 
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Function2.c \ 
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Function3.c \ 


INCLUDE = $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIR))
OBJS=${SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o}
CFLAGS   = $(OPTS) $(INCLUDE) $(DEBUG)

TARGET = $(BINDIR)/ Functions

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS) 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Functions.c has a main inside that calls Function1(); .....Function3();

I'm trying to add the debug flag based on #ifndef

How to add a debug flag and set the Debug compiler directive inside this Makefile? I have #ifndef NDEBUG...#endif from Functions.h

Comment: What are you trying to make? If you're making something named `Functions` in the `$(BINDIR)` directory, then try taking the space out in your `TARGET=` line, so `TARGET = $(BINDIR)/Functions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TARGET = $(BINDIR)/ Functions
```

should be ?

```
TARGET = $(BINDIR)/Functions
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with SRCS....SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Function2.c \ 
SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Function3.c \ ?

Comment: @Ichihara26 Take out each `SRCS=` after the first one. The backslash at the end of the line will continue the line.

Comment: It only gives me one object file Function3.o inside obj folder

Comment: I removed SRCS= after first one, but it starts to complain *** missing separator.  Stop.
I tried TAB before every $(SRCDIR) except first one with Functions.c\. It's still not solving my problem.

Comment: Does it work if you make it one long line? `SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/Functions.c $(SRCDIR)/Function1.c`...

Comment: I got another warning while doing this in one line:
gcc -W -O3 -I./inc  -c src/Function1.c -o obj/Function1.o
In file included from src/Function1.c:5:
./inc/Function1.h:4: warning: data definition has no type or storage class....
Something wrong with my head file?

Comment: Never mind. I tried SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/*.c and this finally worked. Thanks for the help any way.

Answer (score 0):

```
CC=gcc
OPTS=-W -O3
DEBUG=
RM=rm

SRCDIR=src
OBJDIR=obj
INCDIR=inc
BINDIR=bin

SRCS=$(SRCDIR)/*.c

INCLUDE=$(addprefix -I, $(INCDIR))
OBJS=obj/Functions.o obj/Function1.o obj/Function2.o obj/Function3.o
CFLAGS = $(OPTS) $(INCLUDE) $(DEBUG)

TARGET = $(BINDIR)/Functions

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
  $(RM) -f $(TARGET) $(OBJDIR)/*.o
```

I couldn't get your OBJS expansion working, but the adove works on my end.

Comment: I would expand those wildcards `*`, and you could replace `rm` with `$(RM)`. And putting a `-r` on `rm` scares me, since you don't need it here. If you forget to set `$(BINDIR)`, then you just deleted everything on your system that you had access to.